# I get an error when using shap.plots.waterfall after generating the shap values

Tags: python-3.x, shap, waterfall

For the code given below, if I just use the command `shap.plots.waterfall(shap_values[6])` I get the error

> 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'base_values'

I have to firstly run these two commands:

```
explainer2 = shap.Explainer(clf.best_estimator_.predict, X_train)
shap_values = explainer2(X_train)
```

and then run the `waterfall` command to get the correct plot.  Below is an example of where the error occurs:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pickle
import joblib
import warnings
import shap
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV, GridSearchCV

f, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2,figsize=(20,8))
# Generate noisy Data
X_train,y_train = make_classification(n_samples=1000, 
                          n_features=50, 
                          n_informative=9, 
                          n_redundant=0, 
                          n_repeated=0, 
                          n_classes=10, 
                          n_clusters_per_class=1,
                          class_sep=9,
                          flip_y=0.2,
                          #weights=[0.5,0.5], 
                          random_state=17)

X_test,y_test = make_classification(n_samples=500, 
                          n_features=50, 
                          n_informative=9, 
                          n_redundant=0, 
                          n_repeated=0, 
                          n_classes=10, 
                          n_clusters_per_class=1,
                          class_sep=9,
                          flip_y=0.2,
                          #weights=[0.5,0.5], 
                          random_state=17)

model = RandomForestClassifier()

parameter_space = {
    'n_estimators': [10,50,100],
    'criterion': ['gini', 'entropy'],
    'max_depth': np.linspace(10,50,11),
}

clf = GridSearchCV(model, parameter_space, cv = 5, scoring = "accuracy", verbose = True) # model
my_model = clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
print(f'Best Parameters: {clf.best_params_}')

# save the model to disk
filename = f'Testt-RF.sav'
pickle.dump(clf, open(filename, 'wb'))

explainer = Explainer(clf.best_estimator_)
shap_values_tr1 = explainer.shap_values(X_train)

shap.plots.waterfall(shap_values[6])
```

Can you tell me the correct procedure to generate the `shap.plots.waterfall` for the `train` data?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't train a model on one dataset and predict on a different. The whole point of ML is that both should be drawn from a similar (same?) distributions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from shap import Explainer, Explanation
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from shap import waterfall_plot

X, y = make_classification(1000, 50, n_informative=9, n_classes=10)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=.75, random_state=42)
model = RandomForestClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

explainer = Explainer(model)
sv = explainer(X_train)

exp = Explanation(sv[:,:,6], sv.base_values[:,6], X_train, feature_names=None)
idx = 7 # datapoint to explain
waterfall_plot(exp[idx])
```

[image]

Comment: Yes to both, but you can actually check that visually by comparing shap predictions to model predictions, that must be equal when fed the same data

Comment: Thanks sincerely for your solution. I just wanted to get some clarification regarding your solution. In your example, X_train has a shape of (750 x 50). 750 samples with 50 features. For the line of code `exp = Explanation(sv[:,:,6], sv.base_values[:,6], X_train, feature_names=None)`, that specifies that we are looking at class 7? And the `idx' is the sample row 8?

Comment: Thanks again!  I can easily check the model prediction for idx 7 as `predictions = model.predict(X_train);
y_pred = predictions;
y_pred[7]`.  How do I check the `shap` prediction to see if I also get the same answer?

Comment: `0.67` that you see in top right corner of the plot is the proba for class `1`, I believe

Comment: I got an error for `sv`: `too many indices for array: array`. I cannot access like `sv[:,:,6]`. My `sv` contains only `.values`, `.base_values` and `.data`. Some tip about it?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
shap.plots._waterfall.waterfall_legacy(explainer.expected_value[0], shap_values[0].values, df.values[0], feature, max_display=20)
```

[image]